# unfortunately, parseStarterProject has stopped work

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

**ParseApplication firstly adding keys to ParseApplication.java is good but after sdk test show error in device *"unfortunately, parseStarterProject has stopped work"***

**this is my ParseApplication.java file**

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseCrashReporting;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
 public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

// Initialize Crash Reporting.
ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here

  //copy and paste frome parse.com
 // Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);
  Parse.initialize(this, "oaXYWiKShMVJ0VqZ52zwVnzpNlC3CKEReLV5wANX", "BiHRJalzAGYgFmh250SDxBxxi8DaIdnsnfunBfpC");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
// Optionally enable public read access.
// defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
 ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
  testObject.put("foo", "bar");
  testObject.saveInBackground();
}
}
```

**Another, ParseStarterProjectActivity.java file is**

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;



public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());


 }
}
```

***this is doing in android studio and it's a starting project of parse.com "get start project"***

Comment: do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: please,help me to solve this problem I am the new to android and  parse.com.By this time I could not see any stacktrace in logcat.@StefanBeike

Comment: well,by just now I saw the stacktrace in logcat `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id` please sir find it out

Comment: You can check this link out, it helped me. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881052/setreadaccess-error-for-new-parseobject

Comment: check my answer here

[My answer in link below fixed it for me.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335368/parse-unfortunately-application-has-stopped-working-continuously-on-background

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio as a working environment....then what you just need is exit the android studio and then again open it and run your project it solve my problem......I think your will also help likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser(); from your code then try again?